# Flutter custom radio widget with images

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a custom radio widget with images. Question: Let's say I need an image from a group to change when the user clicks on it to show that this particular button is activated. How can I implement this?

```
class _RadioWidgetState extends State<RadioWidget> {
  int _radioValue = 0;
  void _handleRadio(int value) {
    setState(() {
      _radioValue = value;
      switch (_radioValue) {
        case 0:
        break;
        case 1:
          break;
        case 0:
          break;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
      Expanded(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => setState(() {
            _radioValue = 0;
            print(_radioValue);
            _handleRadio(0);
          }),
          child: Container(child: Image.asset('assets/images/asset1.png')),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => setState(() {
            _radioValue = 1;
            print(_radioValue);
          }),
          child: Container(child: Image.asset('assets/images/asset2.png')),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => setState(() {
            _radioValue = 2;
            print(_radioValue);
          }),
          child: Container(child: Image.asset('assets/images/asset3.png')),
        ),
      ),
    ]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the _radioValue to change the image

```
child: Container(child: Image.asset(_radioValue == 0 
  ? 'assets/images/asset1_selected.png' 
  : 'assets/images/asset1.png')
),
```